# Dropping rows from a PANDAS dataframe where some of the columns have value 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am dropping rows from a PANDAS dataframe when some of its columns have 0 value. I got the output by using the below code, but I hope we can do the same with less code — perhaps in a single line.

df:

```
    A   B   C
 0  1   2   5
 1  4   4   0
 2  6   8   4
 3  0   4   2
```

My code:

```
 drop_A=df.index[df["A"] == 0].tolist()
 drop_B=df.index[df["C"] == 0].tolist()
 c=drop_A+drop_B
 df=df.drop(df.index[c])
```

[out]

```
    A   B   C
 0  1   2   5
 2  6   8   4
```

Comment: Do you want to know a better way to do what your code is doing, or do you want us to code golf it?

Comment: I need a better way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need create boolean DataFrame by compare all filtered columns values by scalar for not equality and then check all `True`s per rows by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = df[(df[['A','C']] != 0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  5
2  6  8  4
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[['A','C']] != 0)
       A      C
0   True   True
1   True  False
2   True   True
3  False   True

print ((df[['A','C']] != 0).all(axis=1))

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

I think you need create boolean DataFrame by compare all values by scalar and then check any `True`s per rows by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and last invert mask by `~`:

```
df = df[~(df[['A','C']] == 0).any(axis=1)]
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[['A','C']])
   A  C
0  1  5
1  4  0
2  6  4
3  0  2

print (df[['A','C']] == 0)
       A      C
0  False  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
3   True  False

print ((df[['A','C']] == 0).any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

print (~(df[['A','C']] == 0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Jezrael , I want to consider only column A and C , pls check my question once

Comment: @pyd Clarify this in your question.

Comment: You have both "all not equal to 0" and "not any equal to zero". Did you intend these to be two options, or did you accidentally post two solutions?

Comment: @Accumulation No, it was no accident. I post first the best solution and second very nice, the best 2. :)

Answer (score 4):

One line hack using `.dropna()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,6,0],'B':[2,4,8,4],'C':[5,0,4,2]})
print df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  5
1  4  4  0
2  6  8  4
3  0  4  2

columns = ['A', 'C']
df = df.replace(0, pd.np.nan).dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset=columns).fillna(0).astype(int)

print df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  5
2  6  8  4
```

So, what's happening is:

1. Replace `0` by `NaN` with `.replace()`
2. Use `.dropna()` to drop `NaN`  considering only columns `A` and `C`
3. Replace `NaN` back to `0` with `.fillna()` (not needed if you use all columns instead of only a *subset*)
4. Correct the data type from `float` to `int` with `.astype()`

Comment: Nice! I was hoping there was .dropna() hack to be had... good one paulo!

Comment: Just tried this and received the following:
FutureWarning: The pandas.np module is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import numpy directly instead

Comment: Sure, just import numpy directly (`import numpy as np`) and replace `pd.np.nan` with `np.nan` instead.